# MouseMove over DrawLine C#

Tags: c#, .net, drawing

I have a line class

```
public class Line
{
    public Point pt1 { get; set; }
    public Point pt2 { get; set; }
}
```

Created a list

```
List<Line> lines = new List<Line>();
```

PaintEventHandler, MouseEventHandler & add points to the list in Form()

```
this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(DrawLines);
this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(MouseMoveLines);

lines.Add(new Line()
{
    pt1 = new Point(3, 3),
    pt2 = new Point(120, 120)
});
```

Then i am going to draw the lines.

```
private void DrawLines(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Line l in lines)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, l.pt1, l.pt2);
    }
}

private void MouseMoveLines(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // I need some magic...
}
```

Is there a way to detect the line?

For example;

I need to detect and select the line, and optional you can delete the line.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your question is completely unclear.

Comment: see topic, sorry. I need to detect if there is a line, so i can select them and optional delete them if i want to

Comment: If you know the line coordinates, you should use them to calculate whether the mouse coordinates are on a line. It is completely independent from drawing (at least, I hope you didn't want to observe the pixel colors under the mouse...)

Comment: As @taffer says, you should calculate if the mouse coordinates are on the line. Just another thing: A few years ago I was trying to achieve the same thing and I remember I had to use a kind of "acceptable offset" when clicking on the line like "take the click as a click on the line even if it's not exactly on it", because we are talking about pixels and it's really hard to click exactly on a line in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that

```
public static double GetDistanceBetweenLineAndPoint(this MathDefinitions.Vector2 point, MathDefinitions.Vector2 linePoint1, MathDefinitions.Vector2 linePoint2)
{
    var direction = (linePoint2 - linePoint1);
    var normalizedCopy = direction.NormalizedCopy;
    double len = direction.Length;
    if (len < float.Epsilon) return (point - linePoint1).Length;
    var delta1 = point - linePoint1;
    var delta2 = point - linePoint2;
    double t = delta1.NormalizedCopy.Dot(normalizedCopy);
    if (t <= 0.0) return delta1.Length;
    double t2 = delta2.NormalizedCopy.Dot(normalizedCopy);
    if (t2 >= 0.0) return delta2.Length;
    MathDefinitions.Vector2 proj = linePoint1 + (t * delta1.Length) * normalizedCopy;
    return (point - proj).Length;
}
```

You will get nearest distance from your mouse position to line.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a line remove it from `lines` (For example `lines.RemoveRange(0,1)`) then recall `drawLines()`. Make sure to add `Graphics.Clear()` inside `drawLines()` before the foreach loop so that the old lines won't stay there after they have been removed from the list. Before you use `MouseMoveLines()` you'll probably also want to check if the mouse is down before moving any lines. This can easily be achieved using a mouse down and mouse release event. I can't with the actual hit detection and logic of `MouseMoveLines()` because we would need more than context than that. This question seems very localized and what it's asking isn't even quite clear, but I hope I've helped in some way, and good luck with whatever it is you're making.